# iTunes Store Operation Failed description length, Error ITMS-90046 "Invalid Code Signing Entitlement"

Tags: store, itunes, ios11, operation, xcode9.1

I have no idea how the description length is so long. Inside the Itunes Connect portal, my release descriptions are very short.

How do I change this inside Xcode?

I've tried using the Application Loader and other versions of Xcode but get the same error.

Any suggestions appreciated.

[image]

- iTunes Store Operation Failed description length:8874057
- iTunes Store Operation Failed ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing
  Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code
  signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically,
  value 'kshf.test-app.link' for key
  'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in
  'Payload/HotelBids.app/HotelBids' is not supported."

> Mac OS 10.13.1 XCode 9.1 GM (9B55)

Comment: What is the output to `codesign -d --entitlements :- HotelBids.app/HotelBids` and how have you configured the entitlements.plist-file?

Comment: @Mats, i figure out issue, it is in entitlements.plist file, i have to replace with "applinks:kshf.test-app.link".. App is uploaded successfully.

Comment: @Mehul Did that resolve the description length issue as well? I have a different kind of secondary issue but am also getting the description error. No idea where or how to fix that.

Comment: @CBGrey, Yes, issue hase been resolved by itself after replace applink .